# How to set rich:calendar Date via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xhtml, richfaces, setvalue

I have the following components on xhtml page.

```
<h:inputText id="dateFromText" value="#{fileSearchCriteria.fromDateStr}">
    <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="datePanel1" 
        onchange="checkdate();"  >
</h:inputText>


   <rich:calendar id="fromDate" style="width:175px;"
        popup="true" 
        howInput="false"
        enableManualInput="true"
        firstWeekDay="1" 
        value="#{fileSearchCriteria.fromDate}"
        inputClass="calendar" locale="${externalContext.locale}"
        datePattern="dd.MM.yyyy" >

   </rich:calendar>
```

I'd like to set value to rich calendar by javascript function if inputted text date is correct.

```
function checkdate() {
         var txtDate = document.getElementById('dateFromText').value;
         var fromDate = document.getElementById('fromDate');

        if (chkdate(txtDate)){ 
          txtDate = txtDate.replace(new RegExp("\\.",'g'),'/');
          date1 = new Date(txtDate);
          //fromDate.value = date1 <== Problem !!!!!

        } else {alert("Incorrect date");}
    }
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set value to standard calendar's input.
You may hide it,in case you use your input text.

Comment: It's good idea. I've tried to set value (date as string in corresponding format) to input of calendar like document.getElementById('filesearch-form:fromDateInputDate').value = dateStr; and it works;